# Do I need to create multiple DAGs or one DAG and multiple tasks?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pymongo, airflow

I am struggling with understanding do I need to be creating multiple DAG's or just multiple tasks for what I am doing.  The whole process kicks off every so many hours or when manually triggered.  Here is the gist:

1. Loop through a set of tests
2. Run a test.
3. Check results

   - If the tests pass then move to the next set of tests.
   - If the tests fail, log the failure information (time, reason, what test was ran) in a database.
4. Send message out about failures.

Right now I have the same thing going but am using Celery Beats to kick off the whole thing periodically and I would like to migrate to Airflow.

Here is some of the code I have so far:

```
def check_test_status(**kwargs):
    try:
        test_case = kwargs.pop('test_case', None)
        url = [ line.strip('\r\n') for line in open(os.getenv('TEST_SITES','test_sites.txt'),'r')]
        test_user = test_case['username']
        test_pass = test_case['password']
        test_ip = test_case['ip']
        test_port = test_case['http test port']
        proxies = {
                   'https':'http://{0}:{1}@{2}:{3}'.format(test_user, test_pass, test_ip, test_port),
                   'http':'http://{0}:{1}@{2}:{3}'.format(test_user, test_pass, test_ip, test_port)
                  }
        test_session = requests.Session()
        response = test_session.get(url, headers=headers, proxies=proxies, stream=True, timeout=8, allow_redirects=False)
        ret_code = response.status_code
        if response.ok or response.status_code in app.conf['ACCEPTED_CODES']: 
            return True, ret_code
        else: 
            return False, ret_code
    except Exception as exc:
        import traceback
        test_checker_logger.error('[x] Error {0}'.format(traceback.format_exc()))
        return str(exc)


def already_failed(**kwargs):
    test_id = kwargs.pop('test_id', None)
    result = test_conn.find_one('test_down', {'test_id':test_id})
    test_checker_logger.info(result)
    if result:
        if incr_down_count(test_id=test['_id'], client=client) == 2:
    else:
        update_test_status(status='false', client=client, test_id=test['_id'])

args = {
    'owner':'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': days_ago(2),
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=1)
}

dag = DAG(
    dag_id = 'checker_python_operator',
    default_args = args,
    description = 'Test suite testing  workflow Python DAG',
    schedule_interval = None
)

test_conn = MongoHook(conn_id='test_selector_mongo')
test_list = test_conn.find('test_info', None).limit(1)
for count, test_case in enumerate(test_list):
    check_status_task = PythonOperator(
                     task_id='check_test_status_'+str(count),
                     python_callable=check_test_status,
                     op_kwargs={'test_case':test_case},
                     provide_context=True,
                     dag=dag)
    already_failed_task = PythonOperator(
                          task_id='already_failed_' + str(count),
                          op_kwargs={'task_id':'check_test_stats_'+str(count)},
                          python_callable=already_failed,
                          provide_context=True,
                          dag=dag)

   check_status_task>>already_failed_task
```

Do I need to be creating multiple DAG's or just multiple tasks for what I am doing?  Am I completely missing the mark on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd create a single DAG for this, and simply chain the tests together. If a test fails, mark the task as failed; the standard configuration is for dependent tasks to then not start.

When you generate a DAG dynamically, you need to make sure that all your tasks, once added to the DAG, are going to stick around forever. If tests can be removed, you probably want to generate a dummy task for those. From the [*Best practices* documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/best-practices.html):

> ### Deleting a task
>
> Never delete a task from a DAG. In case of deletion, the historical information of the task disappears from the Airflow UI. It is advised to create a new DAG in case the tasks need to be deleted.

This means that if a test is deleted, and no task is generated for the test, then you can no longer see how that deleted test was run in the past. If instead you placed a dummy task in their place, you can still see how the test was executed in the past before it was deleted.

Taking your requirements:

> 1. Loop through a set of tests
> 2. Run a test.
> 3. Check results
>
>    - If the tests pass then move to the next set of tests.
>    - If the tests fail, log the failure information (time, reason, what test was ran) in a database.
> 4. Send message out about failures.

Step 1. is you generating a DAG from your PyMongo source (taking care to replace deleted test with dummies, so track somewhere what tasks you created)

Step 2. is running the test in a task.

Step 3 is *the same task* checking the results; if the task failed, set the task instance state to failed by raising a `AirflowException` exception. Almost any exception will do, but `AirFlowException("reason")` is just a little cleaner.

Step 4 is a task that depends on all the test tasks, and runs unconditionally (regardless of the test outcomes), and creates and sends the email as the last step in the DAG. You want to set it's [`trigger_rule` value](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/concepts.html#trigger-rules) to `all_done` to accomplish this; it'll run once all of the tasks it depends have succeeded, have failed or have been skipped.

Do note that tasks will be retried if you give them a `retries` value greater than 0; for your tests you probably want to set that to 0.

So, to generate the DAG, you'd use:

```
test_tasks = []
last_test = None

for count, test_case in enumerate(test_list):
    check_status_task = PythonOperator(
        task_id='check_test_status_'+str(count),
        python_callable=check_test_status,
        op_kwargs={'test_case': test_case},
        provide_context=True,
        retries=0,  # no retrying when it fails
        dag=dag,
    )

    if test_tasks:
        # add task to pipeline defined by all tasks running in series
        check_status_task << test_tasks[-1]
    test_tasks.append(check_status_task)

email_result_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='email_result',
    python_callable=email_result,
    provide_context=True,
    # run when all parent tasks are done, regardless the outcome
    trigger_rule='all_done',
    dag=dag
)
test_tasks >> email_result_task
```

The above code builds the dependency graph by taking each preceding test (`test_tasks[-1]`) as the upstream task for the one just generated in the loop. The mail task depends on the whole list of test tasks.

Note that because you set `provide_context=True` and provide a `op_kwargs` dictionary, you can just give your operators direct arguments for any specific context or `op_kwargs` names you need access to in your function. The `check_test_status()` then becomes:

```
from airflow import AirflowException

def check_test_status(test_case, **kwargs):
    # run the test, get the result
    ...

    if test_failed:
        # log failure in database
        ...
        # then mark this task as failed
        raise AirflowException("Test <testcase> failed: ...")
```

The `raise AirflowException()` line causes this test task to be marked as failed, and **all other test tasks in your DAG** will not run now because they use the default `trigger_rule='all_success'` trigger rule.

If you use a `return` in your PythonOperator function, instead, then the returned value is simply discarded unless you use `xcom_push=True` on the task, at which point it is pushed to a dedicated XCom variable for that task, `airfow.models.XCOM_RETURN_KEY`. Personally, I prefer using dedicated Xcom variables, especially when you also need to mark tasks as failed by raising exceptions.

So, for the final email task, you could use a `XCom` variable to pass information from any test tasks that did run onwards; anything that can be pickled or serialized to JSON (depending on your Airflow configuration) can be shared this way.

```
XCOM_TEST_STATUS_KEY = "check_test_status"

def check_test_status(test_case, ti, **kwargs):
    # run the test, get the result
    ...

    test_status = {
        # ... information to share with the mail task            
    }

    ti.xcom_push(XCOM_TEST_STATUS_KEY, test_status)

    if test_failed:
        # log failure in database
        ...
        # then mark this task as failed
        raise AirflowException("Test <testcase> failed: ...")
```

and then in the email task:

```
def email_result(dag, ti, **kwargs):
    test_tasks = [id for id in dag.task_ids if id.starts_with('check_test_status_')]
    test_results = ti.xcom_pull(
        task_ids=test_tasks,
        key=XCOM_TEST_STATUS_KEY,
    )
    # process test_results to produce an email
```

Comment: Your response was immensely helpful!  I really appreciate at it.  Thank you.

Comment: One follow up, is there any benefit in creating a custom operator (ie CheckTestStatusOperator) versus what I am doing now?

Comment: @user982599 I’d not bother with a custom operator class, no. Do that if you need to reuse code across many DAGs or between projects, or need to do things that a standard operator can’t do directly.